Issue with simplifying an expression with "ConjugateTranspose"
Why does the output [6] have Conjugate in it even when I explicitly mention that $c>b$ and all other parameters are real?
 In[1]:= $Assumptions = 
 a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0 && c > b && t > 0 && t > 0 && p > 0

Out[1]= a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0 && c > b && t > 0 && t > 0 && p > 0

In[2]:= H = ( {
    {a - I b, c},
    {c, a + I b}
   } );
ket\[Psi]in = ( {
   {p},
   {1 - p}
  } ); bra\[Psi]in = ( {
   {p, 1 - p}
  } );
Ut = FullSimplify[MatrixExp[-I*H*t]];



In[5]:= 
v1 = FullSimplify[Ut . ket\[Psi]in]

Out[5]= {{E^(-I a t) (p Cos[Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2] t] + (
     I (c (-1 + p) + I b p) Sin[Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2] t])/
     Sqrt[-b^2 + 
      c^2])}, {E^(-I a t) (-((-1 + p) Cos[
         Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2] t]) + ((b - (b + I c) p) Sin[
       Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2] t])/Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2])}}

In[6]:= v1prime = FullSimplify[ConjugateTranspose[v1]]

Out[6]= {{E^(I a t)
    Conjugate[
    p Cos[Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2] t] + (
     I (c (-1 + p) + I b p) Sin[Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2] t])/
     Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2]], 
  E^(I a t) (-((-1 + p) Cos[Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2] t]) + ((b - b p + 
        I c p) Sin[Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2] t])/Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2])}}


If you look at v1 it has complex $i$ in it already.

Thanks @Nasser.  How to make Mathematica simplify  v1 and v1prime?

You already calling FullSimplify on these OK. The issue is that your Ut is complex. Also your H has complex numbers in it.  Hence everything else from then on will be complex. So I am not sure what output you are looking for at the end.

You could try v1prime = Simplify[ComplexExpand@ConjugateTranspose[v1]]
